# Vanishing ideals and kernels of a mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have a polynomial mapping $f: \mathbb{K}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^n$. If we were to find the vanishing ideal of the image of $f$, is it not the same as finding the kernel of the mapping?

Edit: To add more context consider discussion provided by Seth Sullivant [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuApD.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukeF5.png) regarding finding the vanishing ideal of a polynomial mapping. I am interested in knowing why the command $kernel$ was used in the Macaulay2 code. Namely, what is the connection between a kernel of homo/isomorphism and the task of finding a vanishing ideal? Moreover, is there some caveat to this, or can and should I always perform actual computations like discussed in the pages above?

Comment: You mean the kernel of the induced map on coordinate algebras, right?

Comment: In contrast with KReiser, I'm going to assume you mean exactly what you wrote, so the answer is no. A polynomial mapping is not a homomorphism of vector spaces except when it is a linear map in the sense of linear algebra (meaning that the $n$ coordinate functions are *homogeneous* linear polynomials without a constant term). This can be seen easily from the identity $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$ (of course this does suggest a homomorphism in characteristic $2$, but that is somehow beside the point). However, as KReiser alluded to, there is an induced map of $\mathbb K$-algebras to consider.

Comment: @KReiser Perhaps? I am new to algebraic geometry, so I don't know the vocabulary yet. One of my problems were to find a vanishing ideal of the image of a polynomial mapping, and I was wondering does the setting have an analogy in abstract algebra.

Comment: @Qwaster Perhaps I shouldn't have been so eager to guess at your meaning. What do you mean, "kernel of the mapping"?

Comment: @KReiser With "the mapping" I was referring to the polynomial mapping $f$ that maps some indeterminants to other indeterminants. As a vanishing ideal consists of polynomials that map to zero w.r.t. some points (a variety), I was wondering does this have an analogy to kernels of homo/isomorphism. Namely, do we have some correspondence between a kernel and a vanishing ideal of the image set of a polynomial map?

Comment: The fact you've never written "coordinate algebra", "ring of functions", or "$k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$" anywhere has made it really hard to figure out what you're talking about. If you can't clarify your intentions here, I think it's going to be difficult for any further productive discussion to happen. On the other hand, if you are indeed talking about the kernel of the map between the algebras of polynomial functions on each $k^n$ given by composing with $f$, then there's fun and interesting stuff to say here and I'd be happy to write a bit of explanation.

Comment: @KReiser I know this might be annoying to hear, but a reason why I left out those terms is that I did not know what they mean, and thus why they are relevant for the question. A point taken, so to be more explicit: Given a polynomial map $f: \mathbb{C}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^4$, $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) \mapsto (a_1a_3, a_1a_4, a_2a_3, a_2a_4)$ determine the vanishing ideal of the image set of $f$. 

So for this I was wondering can we argue something with the kernel.

Comment: Kernel of what? Kernels are associated to maps. Which map do you mean?

Comment: @KReiser with the kernel of $f$. I do not know does it make any sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115048/discussion-between-kreiser-and-qwaster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a polynomial mapping $(f_1,\cdots,f_n)=f:k^m\to k^n$, you get a homomorphism $f^*:k[y_1,\cdots,y_n]\to k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ sending $y_i$ to $f_i$, where $k[y_1,\cdots,y_n]$ is the algebra of polynomial functions on $k^n$ and $k[x_1,\cdots,x_m]$ is the algebra of polynomial functions on $k^m$ (these are usually referred to as "coordinate algebras" associated to $k^n$ and $k^m$, respectively). This map is the pullback along $f$: given a polynomial function $\varphi$ on $k^n$, we get a polynomial function on $k^m$ by first applying $f$ to get a point in $k^n$ and then applying $\varphi$.

If we want to know what functions vanish on the image of $k^m$ under $f$, it's equivalent to computing what functions pull back to $0$ along $f$, or what the kernel of $f^*:k[y_1,\cdots,y_n]\to k[x_1,\cdots,x_m]$ is. This is exactly what happens in your second linked picture.

This generalizes a lot! One can replace $k^m$ and $k^n$ with any affine varieties $X$ and $Y$ you choose, and the same procedure of writing down the induced map on coordinate algebras and computing the kernel will give you equations for the closure of $f(X)\subset Y$. If this is the sort of thing that interests you, you may wish to peruse some introductory algebraic geometry texts - there are questions here on MSE with recommendations, or your instructor may have suggestions for something comparable to the level and pace of things that you're encountering in this course.